# RBAC with Kubernetes API Server URL based access

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-apiserver

I am accessing Kubernetes API through an HTTP client. I would like to be have access limited to a few resources. For instances, I should be able to list jobs, but not pods.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: job-runner    
---    
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: job-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]    
---    
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: job-runner
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: job-runner # Name of the ServiceAccount
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role # This must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: job-runner # This must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I get the token for this service account by doing this:

```
kubectl get secret `kubectl get sa job-runner -o json | jq -r '.secrets[0].name'` -o json | jq -r '.data.token' | base64 -D
```

Using this token, I run these:

```
curl https://<k8s master ip>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --insecure
curl https://<k8s master ip>/apis/batch/v1/namespace/default/jobs --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --insecure
```

I expect to get access denied for the first request, while getting valid results for the second. However, I get results in both cases.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the output of this command here ? `kubectl get rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io  -o  jsonpath='{range .items[*]}"binding="{.metadata.name} "service-aacount="{.subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name}{"\n"}{end}'|grep job-runner`

Comment: My guess is you are having a clusterrole binding or  rolebinding for pod.

Comment: I get `"binding="job-runner "service-account="job-runner"`

Comment: is there any cluster role for `job-runner` service account ?

Comment: you can check it via `kubectl  get clusterrolebinding  -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {.subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name}{"\n"}{end}' |grep job-runner`

Comment: also, run `kubectl auth can-i get job --as system:serviceaccount:default:job-runner`

Comment: `can-i` returns yes for both job and pod. Also, there are no clusterrolebindings with this name. However, there is something odd here, which I am still to locate. I tried the same rbac in a seprate k8s cluster and the behavior is as per expectations.

Comment: Now that I know the question. I ran the exact commands and I DO get Forbidden error when I access the pods URL. You must have another variable in your env.